# Casting with type parameters in java

Tags: java, generics

Say I have a class like this:

```
class ParameterizedType<T>{
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if (ParameterizedType<T>.class.isInstance(o)){
            ParameterizedType<T> other = (ParameterizedType<T>) o;
            return this.toString() == other.toString();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can get two different warnings from eclipse in such a method.

1. `ParameterizedType<T>.class` is not syntactically correct
2. `(ParameterizedType<T>)` o is an unchecked cast

How could one get around this?

Comment: @kocko has the right information. To get around this you need to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Eclipse gives helpful hints when you hover over the warning. By putting this in you are telling yourself, and other developers, that yes I acknowledge that this is unchecked but I need to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to implement equals by comparing string references? It's bad practice to calculate `equals` by referring to the `toString` method anyway, but comparing strings with `==` is a [serious mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `ParameterizedType<T>.class` is not syntactically correct

The reason for this is that with `.class` you're referring the `.class` value at Runtime and since Generics is a compile-time feature of Java and the type parameters get erased and replaced with actual type(s), then the statement doesn't make sense at Runtime and the `<T>` is completely redundant.

Note that the same rule applies for the `instanceof` operator (i.e. you can't do `if (something instanceof SomeGenericClass<T>)`)

2. `(ParameterizedType<T>)` o is an unchecked cast

There's no way to compare an `Object` to `ParameterizedType` unless downcasting. The IDE correctly suggests that the cast is unchecked, but in order to compare the instances, you have to downcast at some point. In this case, adding a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above the method would be fine.

Please also note that [Strings in Java should not be compared with `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)